# Form tag is not working when I add javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is a homework assignment.
In my HTML form tag, the action to go to a new page works on its own. However, once I add `onsubmit="return validate()" method="POST"` input inside the form tag it no longer works. If I remove the JS then my JavaScript does not execute properly on my page.

'''HTML'''

```
    <!-- Action has the fie that will load after successful validation -->

    <!-- When user clicks on submit button, onsubmit get triggered if it return false then action wont triggered. -->

    <form action="/Week 4/confirm.html" onsubmit="return validate()" method="POST" input>
```

Comment: Why do you have `input` at the end of your form tag?

Comment: You should execute the function, rather than returning it through your HTML element, then you should write the function in such a way it returns a value. Returning a function that doesn't return anythingll will result to undefined

Comment: This is how the form/input should be structured:
<form>
  <input>
</form>

Comment: Kindly show your markup and your JavaScript codes.

Comment: Can you show the content of `validate()` and where it is?

Comment: Since it is a homework assignment, please show us what you understand as well such that we are not giving out the plain answer without helping you to learn.

Comment: Hello all, Thanks for your help. I was able to figure it out by going over the professor's instructions and carefully reviewing both HTML and JS file.